# JQuery Mobile - # added to URLs

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I just updated to jquery mobile 1.3.0 and I noticed that # is always added to the URLs. I encountered the problem in google chrome and safari but not in firefox. Here is the URL: http://m.nearbyph.com/streetnames
If you click on the link, after the page load, a # is added to URL.

All my links has data-ajax="false".

I haven't encountered this in the previous version.

Answer (score 0):

This is because your  tags have '#' as value for their 'href' attribute. If u want it to stop you could try this :

```
 $('someanchorelement').click(function(e) {
           e.preventDefault();
           /* ... other code ... */    
    })
```

Comment: Hi Jesse, thanks for the quick response but the value of the href attributes are not '#', it is complete a link to another page. Thanks.

Comment: ah.. yes i was wrong. i went a little deeper, to the level where you see tabs like 'Healthcare' @Gajotres is right though.

Comment: I enabled Ajax by removing data-ajax="false" in my links, and it seems the problem is gone. Anyway, thank you guys!

Answer (score 0):

This is know bug of current 1.3 beta version.

You can wait for new jQM version where this will be fixed.

Or you can take a look at this link: https://github.com/jquery/jquery-mobile/issues/5442

At the bottom you will find link to the fixed file. Disregard its name (it is named navigator.js). Open your jquery.mobile-1.3.0-beta.1.js file (don't use minified version) and change code selected with red color with the code selected in green color.

But I would advise you to wait for the next jQM beta version.